# No best type found for implicitly-typed array Json error

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have an array that is separate named `scheduleList` like :

```
            var scheduleListAll = await DataService.GetSchedule(Id);
            scheduleList = scheduleListAll.ScheduleItems;
```

And I have another array named `doorsForSite` like :

```
           var doorsForSite = new[]
                {
                new { ControllerId ="controller1",ControllerName="C1",IsChecked = "false",
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId="Door1",DoorName="DoorOne"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door2", DoorName = "DoorTwo" }
                        },
                        scheduleList

                    },
                new { ControllerId ="controller2",ControllerName="C2",IsChecked = "false",
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId=  "Door3",DoorName="DoorThree"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door4", DoorName = "DoorFour" },
                            new { DoorId = "Door5", DoorName = "DoorFive" },
                        }

                    }
            };
```

How to include the `first array` into the `second` ?

I tried :

```
           var doorsForSite = new[]
                {
                new { ControllerId ="controller1",ControllerName="Eagle",IsChecked = "false",new object[] { scheduleList },
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId="Door1",DoorName="DoorOne"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door2", DoorName = "DoorTwo" }
                        },
                        scheduleList

                    },
                new { ControllerId ="controller2",ControllerName="NetAxis",IsChecked = "false",new object[] { scheduleList },
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId=  "Door3",DoorName="DoorThree"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door4", DoorName = "DoorFour" },
                            new { DoorId = "Door5", DoorName = "DoorFive" },
                        }

                    }
            };
```

But did not work. What to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a key, you can't directly put array in there.

Something like

```
{ ControllerId ="controller1",ControllerName="Eagle",IsChecked = "false",new object[] { scheduleList },
    Doors = new[]
    {
        new { DoorId="Door1",DoorName="DoorOne"},
        new { DoorId = "Door2", DoorName = "DoorTwo" }
    },
    ScheduleList = scheduleList //like this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked .

```
            var doorsForSite = new[]
                {
                new { ControllerId ="controller1",ControllerName="Eagle",IsChecked = "false",Schedules = scheduleList,
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId="Door1",DoorName="DoorOne"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door2", DoorName = "DoorTwo" }
                        }

                    },
                new { ControllerId ="controller2",ControllerName="NetAxis",IsChecked = "false", Schedules = scheduleList,
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId=  "Door3",DoorName="DoorThree"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door4", DoorName = "DoorFour" },
                            new { DoorId = "Door5", DoorName = "DoorFive" },
                        }

                    }
            };
```